# WPF Combobox with auto-complete/auto-filter?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, combobox, autocomplete

I am eager to find some solid (free, Open Source, or tutorial/example) code to make a WPF Combobox do autocomlete/autofilter as the user types. But everything I've tried so far has had some sort of problem...

- [A Reusable WPF Autocomplete TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete_textbox.aspx) came close, but I can't get it to [work with more than one filter](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=32) (more info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3498233/Thanks-and-a-question.aspx)).
- [WPF autocomplete textbox/combobox](http://www.sottje.net/post/WPF-autocomplete-textboxcombobox.aspx) doesn't work for me because it inherits from UserControl, and thus doesn't support the DataTemplates I need (for showing/selecting the value of one property for an object with multiple properties).
- [Automatically Filtering a ComboBox in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx) didn't work because it doesn't seem to ever find the EditableTextBox portion of the inherited ComboBox code (via `(TextBox)base.GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox")` which seems to always returns null).
- [Building a Filtered ComboBox for WPF](http://dotbay.blogspot.com/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html) just gets stuck in a refresh loop then overflows the stack after I type just a few letters.

Other things I've considered:

- I know that [Windows Forms' Combobox control has AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and I could [embed it in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), but I can't imagine it would play very well with my WPF data bindings.
- Perhaps it is too complex and I need to simplify, maybe by building one-dimensional (single-property) ObservableCollections for the ComboBoxen... However, the challenge of applying multiple filters (one set by another control's value, and one from what the user is typing) to multiple controls using different views of the same DataSet would require a ridiculous amount of processing power to destroy and rebuild the list every time the user types a character!

So... I'm at wit's end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your Combobox has some data source attached to it , 
just make

```
1-IsTextSearchEnabled = true.
2-IsEditable = true.
```

you are good to go

Comment: I would've liked to be able to search over multiple fields (e.g. "value" and "description"), be case-insensitive, etc.--but it is a PITA. Falling back on this, because it does work as expected with templates et al.

Comment: You can filter over multiple fields by creating another property and joining the fields together there. Then set the search field to that one. Since it has all the fields combined that you need the search works. A bit of a hack but gets the job done.

Comment: @ewall you can try https://www.nuget.org/packages/THEFilteredComboBox/ this we created this control because using above properties was not enough

Comment: Should this work for a List<string> with 160K+ computer names?  I'm able to do this in Winforms with no problem but in WPF it makes suggestions as I type but hangs like crazy when I try to click the drop down.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter With a (sorted) KeyCollection of ~7500 string entries as ItemsSource, this works quite well for me. Opening the combobox takes around 5 seconds (with or without search enabled) but the search itself is near instant even on the later entries in the collection. Note that the speed might be because it's a sorted collection, meaning binary search is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:
http://blogs.windowsclient.net/dragonz/archive/2010/02/23/autocomplete-textbox-control-for-wpf.aspx

Comment: Trying it out now... So far, I'm impressed with the author's attention to detail.

Comment: I didn't end up using this on the current project, but I will keep in on hand for future ones, as it is pretty solid. Thanks!

Comment: The link above is dead. But using web.archive.org I found that the code is hosted here http://wpfactb.codeplex.com/ (you can read the article here http://web.archive.org/web/20120421111715/http://blogs.windowsclient.net/dragonz/archive/2010/02/23/autocomplete-textbox-control-for-wpf.aspx)